# Html bootstrap radio button dynamicaly injected with javascript checked by default doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I make my html (using bootstrap) with javascript, then I display it in a div using jquery `.html()`  `$("#mydivid").html(strinhtml);`

Everything works fine exept for the radio button which is not checked. Here is the html injected :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="radio40">Type d'enregistrement :</label>
    <div class="radio">
        <label active=""><input type="radio" name="typerecord" checked="" disabled="">Mesure</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="typerecord" disabled="">Jauge</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

(This html is the one I took from the webpage in google chrome)

The radio are disabled but none of them is checked. I don't unerstand with it doesn't work, here is an image of the result :

[image]

Comment: Use `checked="checked"` or just `checked`.. not checked="". I'd say same rules should apply for disabled. `disabled="disabled"` or just `disabled`

Comment: Should work: https://jsfiddle.net/18ya7dLq/ Which browser are you having trouble with? Maybe you could provide a fiddle that recreates your problem.

Comment: @entiendoNull Problem is that I put `checked="checked"` in my string and it is changed when I inject it in my page, same for disabled ... I'll try to create my problem in a jsfiddle, thanks for helping

Comment: Here is the JsFiddle which is ... working ... I don't understand, it must be something like a conflict https://jsfiddle.net/ou5awxjq/ I do the same in both codes